How to add a command to the bash history in my current terminal from python
I found this soluion to add commands executed with Python in my bash history, but I can't get it to work in my current terminal session. I see the command has been added to the bash history only when I open a new terminal.
I would like to see the command added to bash history in my currect terminal session.

Put history -r in your PROMPT_COMMAND environment variable, so it will reread the file before each command. See https://superuser.com/questions/1158739/prompt-command-to-reload-from-bash-history

In most Unix-like operating systems, including Linux, the command history is typically stored in a file called ".bash_history" in the user's home directory. When you run the "history" command, it displays the contents of this file, showing a list of commands that were previously executed in the current shell session.
However, the history file is only updated with commands once the shell session terminates. This means that any commands executed in the current shell session won't immediately appear in the history output when you run the "history" command. Instead, they will be appended to the history file once you exit the shell session.
The reason for this behavior is to prevent simultaneous or parallel sessions from overwriting each other's command history. Each shell session maintains its own history list in memory, and updates the history file only when the session ends, ensuring that the command history remains consistent and accurate for each session.
If you want to immediately update the history file with the latest commands from the current session, you can use the "history -a" command, which tells the shell to append the current session's history to the history file without waiting for the session to terminate. This can be useful if you want to ensure that your command history is saved before exiting the shell session.
